# How to expand the last column of table to the rest of width?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.frm-find-people table td:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    width: 100px
}

.frm-find-people table td:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-find-people">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The red box *(second `td` of the `table`)* should be expanded to the rest of width. How can I do that?

Comment: this css only no need js or jquery

Comment: @guradio Yes, I attached `javascript` and `jquery` tags because stackoverflow suggested them. I really don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to tables layout rules, no cell can be less than it's content width. So you can set it's width to `100%`, and it will try to fill whatever is left by the **Name** cell:

```css
.label {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}

.input > input {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-find-people">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Name</td>
                <td class="input"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you .. but I missed writing the width for the first column. My question updated. Upvote anyway\

Comment: You're using unnecessary complex selectors, I'm updating them to classes.

Comment: I don't see any `label` tag in your HTML.

Comment: Also why `width: calc(100% - 4px)`? Why `- 4px` ?

Comment: .label is a class name. The -4px offsets the input's border width (2px) * 2. You can use 'box-sizing: border-box' instead or just remove the input's border.

Comment: I see *(about `.lable` class name)*. But are you sure `-4` is right? Because border width is `(1px) * 2`

Comment: the `<input>` default border width is 2px on chrome